# Formatting JSON Data for Postman

Tags: postman

I am trying to send JSON data as POST through POSTMAN but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When your JSON is validated with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) this is the result:

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   {   taco: {     name: "",
>   --^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

The object keys should be strings. This is valid JSON:

> {
>         "taco": {
>               "name": "",
>               "price": "",
>               "photo_url": ""
>         }
>   }

Answer (score 70):

We could format/prettify the JSON request body within Postman.

1. Paste the JSON request body(raw)
2. Select JSON(application/json)
3. Press Ctrl + B

Comment: In mac, use Command + B

Comment: Posting a JSON that is `beautified` fails for me, if I `minify` it, it works as expected.

Answer (score 16):

[image]paste in your json and hit the beautify button.

Answer (score 5):

You can use simple quote (`' or " works`) :

in `headers` put `Content-Type:application/json`

[image: formatting and using json with postman]